# Gradle does not see any dependencies in intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

[image: Screenshot]

I have a problem when creating a project via Gradle in IntelliJ. In the screenshot you can see Gradle doesn't recognize the groovy dependency, I've tried with different versions from 2.2 to 2.5.2.

I deleted the groovy dependency, added JUnit dependency, same error. Any dependency I add, Gradle doesn't seem to recognize/accept. Gradle build from client works fine, but I can't use the libraries I add. Any solution?

I also checked if I'm in the offline mode, I'm not.

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
   id 'java'
}

group 'testartifact'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @user31601 Just added

Comment: @IsvoranAndrei Any errors when importing the Gradle project? Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I can import other project via gradle just fine, I can't create my own project though.

Comment: @IsvoranAndrei [Can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/9BH8B7X.png). See logs for errors. Check that JDK and Gradle versions are valid.

Comment: @IsvoranAndrei the problem only in that view but you can use the libraries? Or libraries are not available when you build/run the project?

Comment: Those red wiggle lines indicate something messed up.  I leanrned to never trust intellij when it comes to loading projects.  first do a `./gradlew assemble` on the command line and see how this fairs.  most likely you will get a proper error that is helpful.